# CSS scroll bar for a display area

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am very new to CSS HTML. I have a minor problem that I want help on.

I have defined the following tag inside my CSS for a display area to show a set of questions. I drew a static border for my display area but sometimes the text inside the display area exceeds the height and flows out. I want to fix this by adding a scroll bar and define a proper height for my display area. I may still not be clear with my question. So I have inserted an image for reference.

```
  #disp_desc{
            position: absolute;
            COLOR:cyan;
            font-size:16px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            width: 55%;
            top: 255px;
            left: 215px;
            margin-left: ;
            margin-right: ;
            text-align: left;
            overflow-y: scroll;
   }

<div id="problemform" class="form-inline">
        <textarea id="probleminput" class="form-inline" type="text" style="display: inline;"></textarea>
        <button id="problemsubmit" class="btn" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

[image: reference iamge]

First Contact is my display area. Ignore the content and the input box. I just want the entire text to fit inside the defined border using the scrollbar.

Also I want the scroll bar to be displayed only when the text size is large enough. Otherwise it gets displayed even for content which is 1-2 lines and scroll bar doesn't make sense for the same. Can I control it with CSS?

Comment: can you post your `markup` too?

Comment: Don't use `position: absolute` for layout. Yes it seems like the solution you're searching for like "position" what is it useful for if it isn't for positioning but no. Big no. It's a recipe for disaster. Yes most of us have tried that when beginning :) Better use floats (and learn what the property `clear` can do and what the concept of *clearfix* is) and `display: inline-block` and later `display: table` and `table-cell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#disp_desc` element has no specified `height`, and being absolutely positioned it has nothing to assume a height from. Therefore your element isn't restricted in height at all and will continue to grow.

To fix this, simply give it a height:

```css
#disp_desc {
    ...
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: One more question if you don't mind answering here. I want my scroll bar to be displayed automatically only when the text size is big enough. I do not want it to be shown when the size of the text is relatively small like 1 or two lines. Then the scroll bar doesn't make sense but it still gets displayed. Can I control this in CSS or do I have to do it in javascript?

Comment: @JimZilla set `overflow-y` to `auto` instead of `scroll`.

Comment: @JimZilla, you might want to add a `max-height` as well as `overflow-y` like @James Donnelly suggested. (just make sure your `max-height` is the same as your `height`).

Answer (score 0):

Position: absolute; works pretty wonky, I would recommend looking into Position: relative; That will allow you to do something like this in the HTML:

HTML:

```
<div class="cyanBox">
    <div id="disp_desc">
        //THIS IS WHERE YOUR TEXT WILL GO
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cyanBox
{
    position: relative; //Adjust with margins if needed.
    height: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
]

#disc_desc
{
    position: relative;
    height:100%; //Setting position relative with height and width 100% will
    width:100%;  //Cause the description to fill the box, and with overflow Auto
    //Font Styling. //On the box, when it is too long a scroll will be made.
}
```